# Escape the @ Symbol in a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am attempting to delete a database entry, and am matching the entry in the database by searching via the user's email. This means a variable with the @ symbol is placed in my database entry as such:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id=$id AND uEmail=$email
```

I understand that the @ symbol has a usage in SQL, so I presume this is the problem with the statement above. I tried removing the email from the statement and just leaving id, and it worked. How can I escape the @ symbol present in the $email variable?

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: Don't do that.  You need to use parameters.

Comment: email need to placed inside quote: DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id=$id AND uEmail="$email"

Comment: Adding quotes works! However, I can see how parameters would be important to prevent SQL injection @SLaks. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You'd escape your values; or better yet, use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables